# Zend Service Amazon - How to search within subcategories?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, api, zend-framework

I am using Zend Service Amazon 2.0 to search for books using a keyword. Right now, the code is searching for ALL books regardless of subcategory. How can I make it only search for UNIVERSITY textbooks, as in the following link?

```
http://www.amazon.co.uk/University-Textbooks/b/ref=amb_link_162814547_4?ie=UTF8&node=511914031&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=left-1&pf_rd_r=0HCH1765DMFTPPTJ0QRG&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=361137207&pf_rd_i=266239
```

Here is my code:

```
    public function amazonsearch($keywords)  {
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'application/libraries/Amazon');
    require_once 'Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';

    $autoloader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array(
        'namespaces' => array(
            'Zend'        => dirname(__FILE__) . '/Zend',
            'ZendRest'    => dirname(__FILE__) . '/ZendRest',
            'ZendService' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/ZendService',
        ),
        'fallback_autoloader' => true));

    $autoloader->register();

    $tag       = ''; // replace with your Amazon app ID
    $appId     = ''; // replace w/ your access key from https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/securityCredentials
    $secretKey = '';
    $query  = new ZendService\Amazon\Query($appId, 'UK', $secretKey);
    $query->Category('Books')->Keywords($keywords)->AssociateTag($tag)->Page(10);
    $data['result'] = $query->search();
    /*var_dump( $data['result']);*/
    $this->load->view('development/amazonsearch',$data);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using 'university' as a `keyword` argument in the request query?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that ZendService\Amazon support this feature - at least there is nothing on it in the documentation. It is easy to implement according to this page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BrowseNodeLookup.html.

You can try to use alternative syntax (http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zendservice.amazon.html#using-the-responsegroup-option)  and pass an BrowseNode argument - arguments are passed to the query so maybe it will work:

```
$amazon->itemSearch(array(
    'SearchIndex'   => 'All',
    'BrowseNode'    => '1000'
    'Keywords'      => $keywords,
    'ResponseGroup' => 'BrowseNodes,Medium'
));
```

And then replace BrowseNode value for specific category.

List of top level nodes: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BrowseNodeIDs.html

I have not tested that because I don't have amazon api credentials.